# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile - fetching shared module version in iOS application

Tags: ios, kotlin, version, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

I'm trying to fetch the shared module version in my KMM project and use it for some internal logic.

On Android side of things I'm setting a variable in the BuildConfig with:

```
buildConfigField("String", "Version", "\"$version\"")
```

and fetching it from there:

```
BuildConfig.Version
```

I'm not sure how to do this for the iOS.

I see that there is an external dependency https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `shared/src/iosMain` you will want a function as the following:

```
fun appVersion(): String {
  return NSBundle.mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as String
}
```

This will pull the version that is defined as the `CFBundleShortVersionString` from your app level `Info.plist`
This entry will look like:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually did something very similar to this yesterday but the version we needed was the shared module version which is different than the project version. In the end I decided to go with the BuildKonfig because some new use cases have appeared and it will be much easier to maintain everything over shared code.

Comment: I misunderstood the need then. I've accomplished this by in Gradle taking the version from the gradle environment, then writing it to a plist file for the app using `PlistBuddy`